# How to show additional data in an existing template by addon - CS-Cart

Tags: hook, add-on, cs-cart

I've placed my customised template in :  advanced_search.post.tpl file in \cscart\design\backend\templates\addons\codes_searching\hooks\common\advanced_search.

: {include file="buttons/button.tpl" but_text=__("search_products") but_onclick=$but_onclick but_href=$but_href but_role="submit-button" but_name=$but_name}

It doesn't work, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no placed hook on **default** advanced_search.tpl file, it doesn't work to creating **advanced_search.post.tpl** hook file.

Your have only one way that **override** template.Because there is no hook to hooking.

You must create

**backend\templates\addons\codes_searching\overrides\common\advanced_search.tpl**

file.

Then copy default **advanced_search.tpl** file content to overriding content, and do your changes.